# Why do I keep getting an error that there's a duplicate field in my Table when it's not true?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am attempting to use Paperclip in my Ruby on Rails project but I keep getting this error in my Terminal:

`SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: image_file_name: ALTER TABLE "orders" ADD "image_file_name"`

I get this right after I type in `rake db:migrate` with a migration file that looks like this:

```
class AddAttachmentImageToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    change_table :orders do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :orders, :image
  end

end
```

However, my schema file looks like this:

`create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "transaction_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.boolean  "shipped"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "name"
    t.text     "email_address"
    t.text     "address_1"
    t.text     "address_2"
    t.text     "city"
    t.text     "state"
    t.integer  "zip"
    t.string   "size"
  end`

I'm sure there's something I'm missing.  If it's not seeing the duplicate in the schema, where is it seeing it?

Comment: Error should refer to the actual table itself, not the schema. You can check the table and see if it contains this column

Comment: @KarthikT Sorry for the n00b question, how do I view the actual database then if it's not in my project's folder?

Comment: @KarthikT -- Nevermind... I figured out how to view columns in a table through the rails console by typing `Order.column_names`

Comment: I would use one of the many sqlite database viewers to view the native database itself, but ya that works too i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your database already has those columns

[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) uses `t.attachment` to input these columns to your db:

```
[attachment]_file_name
[attachment]_content_type
[attachment]_file_size
[attachment]_updated_at
```

Your `t.attachment` basically means you're trying to create one of these columns, but they already exist. The way to fix this is to just get rid of the contents of that migration, run `rake db:migrate` again, then delete the file

Comment: Yeah... I knew that's what was up.  Just didn't know how to actually view the columns in the table itself.  I ran the `rails console` and then typed in `Orders.column_names` to view all columns.  Then ran a migration to delete then re-install the column names.

Comment: No problem! Hope it helped you :)